# Use hardware acceleration on Windows for video analisys

Tags: windows

I'm using this script for PSNR video MXF file analisys:

```
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -i D:\TEST.mxf -i D:\Bars.mxf -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnr_logfile.txt -f null -
```

I've done a lot of testing but I can't use hardware acceleration using an NVIDIA Quadro P4000.
Is it possible to do analysis with hardware acceleration whit this files?

Thanks

Comment: Hardware acceleration isn't something that can just be enabled. It must be programmed into the video codec or filter you're trying to use. (The video container format is irrelevant.) Have you checked that yet?

Comment: Thanks for your help. MXF file has an 'yuv422p' codec. I searched for documents on FFMPEG filters used in my commands but I can't find anything about Hadware acceleration. Do you kindly have any information about it?

Answer (score 0):

You say the two videos have the *yuv422p* codec. That’s uncompressed video, so there’s nothing to accelerate there (except maybe the underlying storage). The *psnr* filter itself does not support GPU acceleration. It is simply not programmed to support it.

There is nothing you can do. At least not with *ffmpeg*.

It could be possible to perform the PSNR calculations on the GPU, but you would have to use a different tool or maybe program it yourself. (If it’s programming, the *ffmpeg* filter could also be changed to use the GPU.) It could also be *infeasible*, meaning that even though the GPU does the math, the overall process would not be faster.